# Erro no codigo fragments

Tags: android

**Alguma Solução para:**
Meus caros funfa tudo direitinho quando executo 1 simples linha de código do fragments da o erro abaixo...
Já testei...  o que é estranho pois eu só passei de 1 projeto pra outro e alterei tudo inclusive a id content_ini...

```
01-09 20:11:01.108 4815-4815/com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication, PID: 4815
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication/com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication.Main2Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0033 (com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication:id/content_ini) for fragment Content_Ini{490f7af #0 id=0x7f0a0033}
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0033 (com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication:id/content_ini) for fragment Content_Ini{490f7af #0 id=0x7f0a0033}
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1413)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3221)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3171)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:560)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7019)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Segue o fragment >>>

```
package com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Content_Ini extends Fragment {


    public Content_Ini() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main2, container, false);
    }

}
```

e Arquivo content_main2>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_ini"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.dutra_pc.myapplication.Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: O layout `content_main2` existe?

Comment: @Isac S vou até editar lá em cima...

Comment: Solução bizarra q obtive foi criar dentro do ConstraintLayout outro ConstraintLayout e funcionou perfeitamente... e passei a id q estava utilizando no ConstraintLayout externo para o interno agora pq só funfa assim vai entender...